# What is reason for mysql database couldn't insert huge data set continuously?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xampp

I'm trying to read given web link, web pages paragraph by paragraph and insert that data into database.

Every time after reading and inserting about 20 web pages that gives following error messages.

I'm working in `Xampp` mysql server. After clearing history,cookies then work again properly. Then after reading web pages and inserting same errors occurs.

Isn't there any proper solution? Some stack overflow question mentioning about some idea to edit some config file.

Because of working me in windows environment I'm not clear about what they are mentioning.They mention increase maximum connection. But not clear about how I can edit some file (Not clear about where store that config file in windows environment) they mentioning.

Error message:

```
 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2137)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
    ... 13 more
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please check your code to make sure you're calling `close()` on your JDBC connections (and your ResultSets) correctly. This smells to me like your MySQL server is being hit with an application (your Java stuff) containing a connection leak.

Comment: @OllieJones I'm closing connection in finally block after inserting my database. Is it want to close some connection reading class too? According to "Vishvesh Phadnis answer" below my problem solved some extend. But after few minutes again same occurred. What the wrong?

Answer (score 1):

in Mysql `my.ini` or it may be `my-default.ini` file set `max_allowed_packet=32M`

after that restart mysql service.

you can specify size as per your need.

or

with mysql command shell

```
shell > mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M
```

Comment: problem solved some extend. Now about five minute read and insert. Then again same happened. How can I solved it?

Comment: Increase size of max_allowed_packet to 500M or 1024M if you have that much memory available.
Please refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: Thanx for in advance. I'm just reading paragraph by paragraph and insert row by row. How that one single sentence per time become too large? Most of people saying memory leak.But I'm closing connection every time after insert data at finally block. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Maduri Be honest I don't have that much experience but do not open   connection object per row.Better to use connection pool

Comment: I will suggest search on stackoverflow or raise question for inserting large data with your data insertion statistics using java